# how can I make when there is new data items in ordering goods can go directly to the tables of goods?

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

good afternoon gan
Sorry want to ask
I'm making an application inventory items
I have a table of data items and goods reception table
all table data inputted by way of import file excel
how can I make when there is new data items in ordering goods can go directly to the tables of goods?
thank you

[this is my controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/giq6m.png)

```html
public function actionImport(){
      $modelImport =  new \yii\base\DynamicModel([
        'fileImport'=>'File Import',
      ]);
      $modelImport->addRule(['fileImport'],'required');
      $modelImport->addRule(['fileImport'],'file',['extensions'=>'ods,xls,xlsx']);
      if(Yii::$app->request->post()){
        $modelImport->fileImport = \yii\web\UploadedFile::getInstance($modelImport,'fileImport');
        if ($modelImport->fileImport && $modelImport->validate()){
          $inputFileType = \PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($modelImport->fileImport->tempName);
          $objReader = \PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
          $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($modelImport->fileImport->tempName);
          $sheetData = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null,true,true,true);
          $baseRow = 1;
          while(!empty($sheetData[$baseRow]['A'])){
            $model = new PersediaanBarang();
            $model->rm_code = (string) $sheetData[$baseRow]['A'];
            $model->quantity = (string) $sheetData[$baseRow]['B'];

            $model->save();
            $baseRow++;

          }
          Yii::$app->getSession()->setFlash('success','Success');
        }else{
          Yii::$app->getSession()->setFlash('error','Error');
        }
        //return $this->redirect(['barang/index']);

      }

      return $this->render('import',[
        'modelImport'=>$modelImport,
      ]);
    }
```

Comment: Hello! Welcome to stackoverflow! Please take the [tour](http://www.stackoverflow.com/tour) so you know how to ask a good question..

Comment: okay @Naruto, i have done to read tour
can you help me to solve my problem? :)

Comment: No, because your question is too broad, add code, make your question more clear, show us what you tried so far, what you are getting, and what the expected result is, any errors...

Comment: okay @Naruto, i will be write my code
i'm sorry to you because i'm very junior in here

Comment: @Naruto 's point was to make you realise your question needs editing before we can provide any answer. Your description is vague and there is no piece of code / db structure provided either. My guess is that this question is only going to attract down- and close votes - unless you change it.

Comment: i'm sorry @Shadow what i have done, i have to edit my question
i'm new in stackoverflow, perhaps i need more learn in here

Comment: I can see that this piece of code imports data from an Excel file, but I have no idea where the data is imported to at the moment and where it should be imported. You probably need to check if the given product exists (rm_code?) in the goods table and if it does not, then insert into the good table. I cannot give you any specific code, since I have no idea how your system works or your schema looks like.

Comment: @Shadow thank you for your helping

Answer (score 0):

SOLVE!!!!

```html
<?php

namespace backend\controllers;

use Yii;
use backend\models\Penerimaan;
use backend\models\PenerimaanSearch;
use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\web\NotFoundHttpException;
use yii\filters\VerbFilter;
use backend\models\Barang;

/**
 * PenerimaanController implements the CRUD actions for Penerimaan model.
 */
class PenerimaanController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'verbs' => [
                'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
                'actions' => [
                    'delete' => ['POST'],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Lists all Penerimaan models.
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        $searchModel = new PenerimaanSearch();
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

        return $this->render('index', [
            'searchModel' => $searchModel,
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Displays a single Penerimaan model.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionView($id)
    {
        return $this->render('view', [
            'model' => $this->findModel($id),
        ]);

    }
    public function actionLihat()
    {
      $connection=  \Yii::$app->db;
      $users = $connection->createCommand('SELECT avg(price) as a FROM penerimaan')->queryAll();
      var_dump($users);
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new Penerimaan model.
     * If creation is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model = new Penerimaan();

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        } else {
            return $this->render('create', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Updates an existing Penerimaan model.
     * If update is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionUpdate($id)
    {
        $model = $this->findModel($id);

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        } else {
            return $this->render('update', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Deletes an existing Penerimaan model.
     * If deletion is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'index' page.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionDelete($id)
    {
        $this->findModel($id)->delete();

        return $this->redirect(['index']);
    }

    /**
     * Finds the Penerimaan model based on its primary key value.
     * If the model is not found, a 404 HTTP exception will be thrown.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return Penerimaan the loaded model
     * @throws NotFoundHttpException if the model cannot be found
     */
    protected function findModel($id)
    {
        if (($model = Penerimaan::findOne($id)) !== null) {
            return $model;
        } else {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException('The requested page does not exist.');
        }
    }
    public function actionImport(){
      $model=new Penerimaan();

      $modelImport =  new \yii\base\DynamicModel([
        'fileImport'=>'File Import',
      ]);
      $modelImport->addRule(['fileImport'],'required');
      $modelImport->addRule(['fileImport'],'file',['extensions'=>'ods,xls,xlsx']);
      if(Yii::$app->request->post()){
        $modelImport->fileImport = \yii\web\UploadedFile::getInstance($modelImport,'fileImport');
        if ($modelImport->fileImport && $modelImport->validate()){
          $inputFileType = \PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($modelImport->fileImport->tempName);
          $objReader = \PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
          $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($modelImport->fileImport->tempName);
          $sheetData = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null,true,true,true);
          $baseRow = 1;
          while(!empty($sheetData[$baseRow]['A'])){
            $x = Barang::find()->where(['rm_code'=>$sheetData[$baseRow]['A']])->count();
            if($x==0){
              $connection = \Yii::$app->db;
              $connection->createCommand()->insert('barang',['rm_code'=>$sheetData[$baseRow]['A']])->execute();

}
            $model = new Penerimaan();
            $model->rm_code = (string) $sheetData[$baseRow]['A'];
            $model->quantity = (string) $sheetData[$baseRow]['B'];
            $bulan = $_POST['Penerimaan']['bulan'];
            $model->bulan= $bulan;

            $model->save();
            $baseRow++;

          }
          Yii::$app->getSession()->setFlash('success','Success');
        }else{
          Yii::$app->getSession()->setFlash('error','Error');
        }
        return $this->redirect(['penerimaan/index']);

      }

      return $this->render('import',[
        'modelImport'=>$modelImport,
        'model'=>$model,
      ]);
    }

    public function actionBarang()
    {
        $searchModel = new PenerimaanSearch();
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

        return $this->render('barang', [
            'searchModel' => $searchModel,
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        ]);
    }


}
```